# Clear a Text Box within tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to refresh a label in a tkinter GUI and its proving very 
difficult.
I have tried the destroy() command and delete command e.g

```
def Erase():
    self.e1.delete(first=0,last=100)
```

I have read many posts and tkinter documentation but had no success

```
def retrieve_inputBoxes():
    VPNID = int(self.e1.get())
    df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
    output = (df[["field1", "field2", "field9"]][df["field4"]== VPNID])
    my_list1 = output["field1"].tolist()
    self.e1 = self.canvas.create_text(100 ,450 ,anchor='center', text=my_list1, font =('Helvetica', 8, 'bold'))
```

The data goes into the label just fine but the next time the data goes in, it overwrites the previous entry.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, could you explain what this part of the program is doing with some context please? And what kind of object is self.e1?

Comment: You say you've tried the destroy command, but your code shows no evidence of that. Please take the time to create a proper [mcve]. Also, your title mentions a "textbox", but tkinter has no such widget. There is an entry widget and a text widget, and then your code is creating a canvas text object. It's hard to say which you're referring to.

Comment: The title should really be clear a "Label" within tkinter

Comment: The title should really be clear a "Label" within tkinter                                                       The code example is a function that reads in an input from a user, the input then looks up a csv file that extracts a row of data based on the users input. The field1 column of the extracted data is put into a list. A label called e1 is setup on the canvas and the text=my_list is displayed on the canvas. This works fine but the next time i look up a new value the label is overwritten with   a new value (looks like its written over it) hence i need to clear the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete method needs to be called on the canvas object, not the variable `self.e1`. The `create_text` method returns an identifier, so this line:

```
self.e1 = self.canvas.create_text(... )
```

assigns that identifier to `self.e1`. 
You can use that variable to tell the delete method what to delete.

```
self.canvas.delete(self.e1)
```